# Restoring value in NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have stored my initial set up values using NSUserDefault like this...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setBool:is_remember_chkd forKey:remember_me.titleLabel.text]; // Button text as key
[defaults setBool:is_signin_auto_chkd forKey:signin_automatic.titleLabel.text];
[defaults setBool:is_signin_secret_chkd forKey:signin_secret.titleLabel.text];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And I retrieved as ....

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
is_remember_chkd = [defaults objectForKey:remember_me.titleLabel.text];
is_signin_auto_chkd = [defaults objectForKey:signin_automatic.titleLabel.text];
is_signin_secret_chkd = [defaults objectForKey:signin_secret.titleLabel.text];
```

But I am not getting the last value, Am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: you store bool values. try [defaults boolForKey:remember_me.titleLabel.text], or try to NSLog [defaults objectForKey:remember_me.titleLabel.text] directly to check if the values match

Comment: Ya you are right, I also noticed now, thanks... :)

Comment: Also, have a look at registering defaults so you don't have to manually write the code to save each one's default value - `-fooForKey:` then returns your default value, but `-setFoo: forKey:` will still save in the normal place. Then to reset to default values you just `-removeObjectForKey:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For retrieved the NSUserDefaults Value , replace the **objectForKey to  boolForKey .**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
is_remember_chkd = [defaults boolForKey:remember_me.titleLabel.text];
is_signin_auto_chkd = [defaults boolForKey:signin_automatic.titleLabel.text];
is_signin_secret_chkd = [defaults boolForKey :signin_secret.titleLabel.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you, extract boolValue from the returned value

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
is_remember_chkd = [[defaults objectForKey:remember_me.titleLabel.text] boolValue];
is_signin_auto_chkd = [[defaults objectForKey:signin_automatic.titleLabel.text] boolValue];
is_signin_secret_chkd = [[defaults objectForKey:signin_secret.titleLabel.text] boolValue];
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)